# How can I change the y-coordinate of Excel 2013 figure to 10 power numbers format

Tags: excel

I have an figure built using Excel 2013,  the y-coordinate values are 1 , 1.0E-01 , 1.0E-02  and so on. I want to change the values of y-coordinate to be 1 , 10^{-1}, 10^{-2}  , I mean similar to that format used in Matlab,  How can I go that?

Thank you

Comment: Are they text or scientific notation in cell? Means excel cell is formatted as `Scientific` or `Text`?

Comment: Now, they are scientific